# To throw a Thread

Tags: java

I have a question.

Would it be possible, hypthetically, in Java, to throw a running thread as exception?
I know this is madness, but just for fun, could it be done? Something along the lines of:

```
public void throwThread() throws ExceptableThread {
    ExceptableThread thread = new ExceptableThread();
    thread.start();
    throw thread;
```

Implementing Runnable as interface is not really an option. It *should* throw the actual thread object.

Comment: since it's not the actual effect of throwing an exception you care about, you can rewrite the question as "can i do mutiple inheritance in java?"

Comment: Well... no... it's not about multiple inheritance in Java, it's about throwing a thread. @Jon Skeet answered my question pretty much perfectly. It was just about the possibility.

Comment: if you could have a class which is both Throwable and Thread then you could probably throw it without problems. That's why i asked about wrapping it in Throwable, it could result in the same and is permitted by language

Comment: I just tried rewriting the Thread class. I would have to alter the whole Native Interface between the OS and the JVM to make my Thread extends Throwable work... So... I take this as a no.

Comment: I have found that the best way to get an answer to "can I do <some crazy thing>" is to try and do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it wouldn't. `Thread` doesn't extend `Throwable`, so you can't throw it.

Even if it were possible, it would be a horrible conflation of two very separate responsibilities, IMO.

Comment: Yes, it would be horrible. I wouldn't do it. I just wanted to know, if it is some how possible... I was just trying to find the most madness in a concept. Throwing a thread as a RuntimeException or Error was about the most idiotic and maddest idea I could come up with.

Comment: Couldn't he wrap the tread in Throwable then? edit: i know it's not what he's asking for, but probably would mean the same thing.

Comment: @soulcheck: You could wrap it in some form, yes - but then you wouldn't be throwing the thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, I was just wondering what he would accomplish throwing a thread that he couldn't accomplish by wrapping it in throwable apart from actually throwing a thread :)

Comment: @soulcheck I am not trying to accomplish anything. It's just a hyptothetical question. I am NOT going to use this in actual code. It's just a question about the language internals, and why, if it is possible, it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can throw an exception with contains a Thread - weird things *_*

Comment: That is just not what I want. Extending Throwable or Exception and implementing Runnable is just not the right thing. Custom exceptions holding a thread object is also not what I want, I want to throw a Thread. A Thread object. ^^ Yes. This is madness.

Answer (score 1):

You can only throw `Throwable`s.